# How can I manually set static html files for each location block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to play with nginx. I am trying to serve a particualar index.html files for each location declared on my configuration file like

```
location / {
    root /usr/src/seo/homepage;
}

location ~ /mypage {
    root /usr/src/seo/mypage;
}

location ~ /mypage2 {
    root /usr/src/seo/mypage2;
}
```

Where each of the folder location specified has it's own index.html file. But when I try to access **mypage** and **mypage2**, nginx returns 404. I am expecting it to render it's respective index.html

**UPDATE!!!**
Solved it using alias like:

```
location / {
    alias /usr/src/seo/homepage;
}

location ~ /mypage {
    alias /usr/src/seo/mypage;
}

location ~ /mypage2 {
    alias /usr/src/seo/mypage2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#root-directory-and-index-files):

> To obtain the path of a requested file, NGINX appends the request URI to the path specified by the `root` directive

I.e. when `/mypage` is requested, nginx tries to find `/usr/src/seo/mypage/mypage`.

To address that, location blocks for `mypage` and `mypage2` should look something like

```
location ~ /(mypage|mypage2) {
    root /usr/src/seo;
}
```

That however requires the request to end with a slash `/` for `index` directive to work. So it might be a good idea to include `try_files`:

```
location ~ /(mypage|mypage2) {
    root /usr/src/seo;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```